# Tricky count groupby in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to groupby ID and find the min and max counts for each month and year.

**Data**

```
DATE        ID  name        
4/20/2023   AA  h88     
4/30/2023   AA  ha4     
4/30/2023   AA  hy66        
4/30/2023   AA  hc      
4/30/2023   AA  jk      
5/30/2023   AA  jk      
5/1/2023    AA  DD      
5/1/2023    AA  vb      
4/20/2023   BB  h88     
4/20/2023   BB  ha4     
4/20/2023   BB  hy66        
4/20/2023   BB  hc      
4/30/2023   BB  jk1     
4/30/2023   BB  jk2     
4/30/2023   BB  jk3     
5/1/2023    BB  DD      
5/2/2023    BB  vb      
5/2/2023    BB  Xx
```

**Desired**

```
ID  Month   Year    stat    count
AA  April   2023    min     1
AA  April   2023    max     4
AA  May     2023    min     1
AA  May     2023    max     2
BB  April   2023    min     3
BB  April   2023    max     4
BB  May     2023    min     1
BB  May     2023    max     2
```

**Doing**

```
# Convert 'DATE' column to datetime format and extract month and year
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df['month'] = df['DATE'].dt.month
df['year'] = df['DATE'].dt.year

# Group by 'ID', 'month', and 'year' and calculate the count of names
result = df.groupby(['ID', 'year', 'month', 'DATE'])['name'].size().reset_index(name='count')

# Find the min and max counts for each ID and month combination
result_min = result.groupby(['ID', 'year', 'month'])['count'].min().reset_index(name='min_count')
result_max = result.groupby(['ID', 'year', 'month'])['count'].max().reset_index(name='max_count')

# Merge the min and max counts with the original result DataFrame
result = result.merge(result_min, on=['ID', 'year', 'month']).merge(result_max, on=['ID', 'year', 'month'])

# Create a 'stat' column based on the min and max counts
result['stat'] = np.where(result['count'] == result['min_count'], 'min', 'max')

# Drop unnecessary columns and reset index
result = result.drop(columns=['min_count', 'max_count']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

However this produces by date. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right:

```py
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

x = (
    df.groupby(["ID", df["Date"].dt.month, df["Date"].dt.year])["Date"]
    .apply(lambda x: {"min": (c := x.dt.day.value_counts()).min(), "max": c.max()})
    .to_frame(name="count")
)
x.index.names = ("ID", "Month", "Year", "stat")
print(x.reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
   ID  Month  Year stat  count
0  AA      4  2023  min      1
1  AA      4  2023  max      4
2  AA      5  2023  min      1
3  AA      5  2023  max      2
4  BB      4  2023  min      3
5  BB      4  2023  max      4
6  BB      5  2023  min      1
7  BB      5  2023  max      2
```

---

EDIT: Version without `:=` operator:

```py
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])


def fn(x):
    tmp = x.dt.day.value_counts()
    return {"min": tmp.min(), "max": tmp.max()}

x = (
    df.groupby(["ID", df["Date"].dt.month, df["Date"].dt.year])["Date"]
    .apply(fn)
    .to_frame(name="count")
)
x.index.names = ("ID", "Month", "Year", "stat")
print(x.reset_index())
```

Comment: thanks it says invalid syntax .apply(lambda x: {"min": (c:= x.dt.day.value_counts()).min(), "max": c.max()})  do I need to remove or add something?

Comment: @Lynn What version of Python are you using? `:=` operator is from version 3.8. I've added version without `:=` operator